# Was Iron Man 3 originally planned to be released around Christmas?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

I just watched Iron Man 3. The whole story takes place during Christmas.
It gives a feeling that we are watching a movie in the holiday season.
I found it a little awkward because I was watching a Summer movie.

So what was the original plan?
Was it planned as a summer movie or a holiday season movie?

Comment: Same question came in my mind too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Director/writer [**Shane Black**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000948/) has a thing for *Christmas*, e.g.

- [Lethal Weapon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093409/)
- [The Last Boy Scout](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102266/)
- [The Long Kiss Goodnight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116908/)
- [Kiss Kiss Bang Bang](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373469/)

take place during the Christmas season.

In [this inteview](http://veryaware.com/2013/04/interview-robert-downey-jr-ben-kingsley-gwyneth-paltrow-don-cheadle-guy-pearce-rebecca-hall-shane-black-drew-pearce-talk-iron-man-3/) he explains:

> ***If you're doing something on an interesting scale that involves a whole universe of characters, one way to unite them is to have them all undergo a common experience, and there's something in Christmas that unites everybody**, it sets a stage within a stage.*
>
> *Also, there's something just pleasing about it to me. We did 'Lethal Weapon' back in ’87 at Christmas and [Joel Silver](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005428/) liked it so much he put ['Die Hard'](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/) at Christmas. There’s fun to that. It’s a time of reckoning for people.*

[and](http://www.wow247.co.uk/blog/2013/04/25/shane-black-iron-man-3-interview-5561/):

> *I think it’s just a universal leveler. An almost magical backdrop that invites a hush, momentary time-out in people’s lives.*
>
> *To have to dig for bits of Christmas, and find that magic in the midst of the tumult of an action film, has a real psychological resonance for me.*
>
> ***We actually started talking about this as ‘[A Christmas Carol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol)’ episode of Iron Man. Certain characters in Iron Man 3 are analogous to different ghosts from the Dickens tale.***

So, setting *Iron Man 3* at Christmas time wasn't tied to the release date.

Comment: +1 Wow, very insightful answer. So it was actually *Shane Black* and *Lethal Weapon* that were the inspriation for THE Christmas action movie of all time (*Die Hard*, of course). Didn't know *Last Boy Scout* took place on Christmas, though (well, who notices that in all-year-sunny L.A.), the only Christmas reference I can remember from it would be *"Satan Claus"*.

Comment: Ironically, _Die Hard_ was released in __July__.

Comment: Associated with movies just so I could upvote this answer. Way to dig into the directors background to provide the actual thinking/reasoning for the setting.

Comment: Well done, Oliver. I just watched Kiss Kiss Bang Bang and this prompted me to do the research which you have just posted - LOL.

Comment: Oliver & Nobby, you both are great :) I mean it.

Answer (score 10):

A press release reported on by [EW.com on October 18, 2010](http://news-briefs.ew.com/2010/10/18/iron-man-3-to-come-to-theaters-2013/) states:

*Disney, Paramount Pictures, and Marvel Studios have announced via press release that Iron Man 3 will be released in on May 3, 2013.*

This suggests that *Iron Man 3* was always intended to be a late spring tent-pole picture in keeping with the previous releases.

We can only speculate the reason behind the Christmas theme, but in my opinion the sense of conclusion to an over all arc spanning three films fits well with a story set at the end of the year; 'out with the old, in with the new' you might say.

Also, I believe that the events in The *Avengers* occurred in the summer, which would be recent enough for Tony's PTSD to be so crippling.

**EDIT:
I was planning to add a whole lot about Shane Black's predeliction for xmas in his stories - but Oliver C. has done the grunt work for me - see his answer above.**